# Parsing CSV with coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I want to create a new function which will take CSV and parse data from it and then write it to database.
So far I managed to get this:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="C:\ColdFusion11\path\test.csv" name="csvData"> 
<cfoutput>#isQuery(csvData)#</cfoutput>

<cfloop query="csvdata" >
    <p>
<cfloop list="#csvdata.columnlist#" index="i">
    <cfoutput>
            #csvdata['#i#'][currentRow]# - 
    </cfoutput>    
</cfloop>
</p>
</cfloop>
```

And I get this error:
Variable CSVDATA is undefined

I don't know why do I get this error, because my var is defined in cfhttp(Or I did something wrong there?)

Comment: Read up on `cfspreadsheet`. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfspreadsheet.html

Comment: *... url="C:\ColdFusion11\path\test.csv"* That is not a valid url.  As the tag name implies, `cfhttp` is used to make an http request, not read files on a local drive.

Comment: Actually, using cfhttp to read files on the server is perfectly valid.  To see an example, go here, http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ffc.html, and look for the section starting with, `Building a query from a delimited text file`.  The syntax for the url is different though, as you pointed out.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Yes, not the clearest wording on my part. What I meant was it requires a URL (ie http|https), rather than a local file path like "c:/path/file.ext".

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno what I figured out was that cfspreadsheet type="csv" just converts the read xls document into csv format. Not sure how usefull that is.

Comment: @T2Admin The first example, and I loathe the Adobe documentation, uses `action="read"` with `query="foo"`. This will read the CSV file and create a ColdFusion query object named "foo", which is very easy to then loop over for inserts into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
<cffile action="read" file="C:\foo\bar\test.csv" variable="csvfile">

<cfloop index="index" list="#csvfile#" delimiters="#chr(10)##chr(13)#"> 
    <cfquery name="importcsv" datasource="#systemDSN#"> 
         INSERT INTO csvdemo (test1,test2,test3,test4) 
         VALUES 
                  ('#listgetAt('#index#',1, ',')#', 
                   '#listgetAt('#index#',2, ',')#', 
                   '#listgetAt('#index#',3, ',')#', 
                   '#listgetAt('#index#',4)#' 
                  ) 
   </cfquery> 
</cfloop>

<cfquery name="rscsvdemo" datasource="#systemDSN#"> 
         SELECT * FROM csvdemo 
</cfquery> 
<cfdump var="#rscsvdemo#">
```

Comment: Most databases provide tools for importing csv files more efficiently ie BULK INSERT, LOAD DATA.. Why not use db tools instead? BTW, always use cfqueryparam (especially when looping).

Comment: Why do it's better to use cfqueryparam ?

Comment: *Why it's better to use cfqueryparam ?

Comment: The primary reasons in this case, are to improve performance (since the queries are executed multiple times) AND to protect your db against sql injection.  Though again, using db tools to import the file is usually faster and more efficient.

Comment: @T2Admin But cfqueryparam have some limitation. If we pass the list values in cfqueryparam means the cfqueryparam allows only 2100 values in to the list. So, more than 2100 values in our list means cfqueryparam throws error.

Comment: @SathishChelladurai - That is usually a database limitation. Most set a hard limit on the maximum number of items you can pass into an IN clause. Though honestly if you hit that ceiling, it is probably time to re-evaluate the approach ...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but still valid.
There are no simple csv tools bundled in cfml but there are plenty of ways to parse csv,
A simple trick is to use cfhttp, but you need to be able to load it over http(s)

```
 <cfhttp method="get" name="CSVQry"
    url="#siteAddress#/data/table.csv"
    firstRowAsHeaders="true"
    columns="#COLUMNLIST#"
    delimiter="#DELIMITER#">
 </cfhttp>
```

A more versatile solution is Ben Nadels csv parser, which I can really recommend.
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/483-parsing-csv-data-using-coldfusion.htm